# Get entity id in hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()

Tags: forms, 8

I am working on porting a D7 module to D8.
As in Drupal 8 all things are represented as entity, menu items are also represented as entity.
Now I added a `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` implementation to alter the menu creation and edit form. On the menu edit form, I want to get the entity ID of the menu that is currently being edited.

I tried to get the entity id ID with the [following code](https://github.com/mohit-rocks/menuicons/blob/master/menu_icons.module), but I am getting an error. (See line 43.)

```
$entity = $form_state['controller']->getEntity();
```

For above snippet I followed https://www.drupal.org/node/1734556.

How can I get the entity ID?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That CR is outdated, probably there's a later CR updating it: now you should use `$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()`.