# Getting the node object in hook_form_FORM_ID_alter

Tags: 8, forms

Follow up to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/142063/get-entity-id-in-hook-form-base-form-id-alter)  but I don't have enough reputation to ask clarification in a comment.

I am porting a contributed module to Drupal 8.
The sugested code on the above mentioned CR and post is not working:

```
$node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
```

Nothing is loaded into the $node variable.

My PHPStorm IDE gives a warning for getEntity():
Method 'getEntity' not found in class Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface less... 
Referenced method is not found in subject class.

It is also not presenting this method for code completion.

In the use cause I am referencing:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PhpStorm doesn't know as the type of form object is dynamic but it's fine.

If you want to make it happy, wrap it in a condition like:

```
if ($form_state->getFormObject() instanceof EntityForm) {
  ...
}
```

Either way, it should definitely work if you implement the correct form alter. If you don't, you should end up with a fatal error not just without a node object.

You need to share your exact code if you want a more specific answer, that's all I can tell you.

Comment: Thanks Berdir. I was not aware $node is not the node object like in D7. So $node->nid does not work, but $node->Id () does.

Answer (score 13):

Though the correct answer has been chosen, I feel there's need to explain some things:

- The method `getFormObject()` is only available on forms of type `EntityForm`.
- If you're doing `hook_form_node_form_alter()`, you know that the form is always a node form, so you're safe calling `getEntity()` on the form object.
- However, if you're doing a general `hook_form_alter()` hook, you might want to check for the correct `$form_id` or check if the form object is actually a `NodeForm` or an `EntityForm`. This will prevent PHP errors if the form is not an entity / node form.
- As for your IDE and code completion, you can tell your IDE that the `$form_object` you're dealing with is a `NodeForm` or an `EntityForm`. This will make it show more appropriate hints.

```php
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityForm $form_object */
$form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();
if ($form_object instanceof EntityForm) {
  $entity = $form_object->getEntity();
  // Do something with the entity.
}
```

Comment: best of them all, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

For your IDE to know what the variable type is and what is available to it, you need to type hint your variables.

The type hint is the variable type added before the parameter variable name (in the example below `array` and `FormStateInterFace`).

Example:

```
/**
 * On form submit, do something.
 *
 * @param array
 *   The form array.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface
 *   The form state array.
 */
function _submit_hook_name(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject();
  // Do something...
}
```

For submit hooks, you should be using the `Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface` type... therefore at the top of the file ensure you use that class `use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;`.

Drupal coding standards states that you should type cast as well as explain the type in the docblock.  The extra effort helps in future. ;)