# Is there any way to show a "computed field" value in edit mode?

Tags: forms, 9

I have a content type (*Structure*) to which I added a text computed field.

In a module I added the following code.

```php
function computed_field_field_reference_compute($entity_type_manager, $node, $fields, $delta) {
  return GedProjectUtils::computeReference($node);
}
```

It works: In view mode, the field is well calculated.

Now I would like to show this field on edit mode. I added this code to the module.

```php
function gedproject_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_structure_edit_form') {
    $form['field_reference']['widget'][0]['value']['#type']='textfield';
    $form['field_reference']['widget'][0]['value']['#title']='Référence';
    $form['field_reference']['widget'][0]['value']['#attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';
  }
}
```

The field is shown empty.

> [image: screenshot]

What do I need to change in the code I added?

Comment: `$form['field_reference']['widget'][0]['value']['#value'] = $value;`

Comment: Thanks, but how to init $value. I found the solution

Answer (score 2):

So the solution found is :
I catched the node id from *$form_state* and then catched the field value from the node like this :

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_form_alter
 *
 */
function gedproject_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_structure_edit_form') {
    $form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();
    if ($form_object instanceof EntityForm) {
      $entity = $form_object->getEntity();
      $value = $entity->get('field_reference')->value;
      $form['field_reference']['widget'][0]['value']['#value'] = $value;
      $form['field_reference']['widget'][0]['value']['#type']='textfield';
      $form['field_reference']['widget'][0]['value']['#title']='Référence';
      $form['field_reference']['widget'][0]['value']['#attributes']['readonly'] = 'readonly';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: solution inspired of : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183413/getting-the-node-object-in-hook-form-form-id-alter